# Resize html widget in Shiny? (echarts4r)

Tags: r, shiny, echarts4r

good afternoon/night. Im trying to create a shiny app with leaflet and echarts4r, but i would like to know if it is possible to change the size of the histogram that appears to the side. Anyone have any ideas on how I could do it? Here is a screenshot to indicate the size that I would be interested in having the graphic:

[SS of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVCDX.png)

The code of the app is the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(htmltools)
library(echarts4r)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                sliderInput("range", "Magnitudes", min(quakes$mag), max(quakes$mag),
                            value = range(quakes$mag), step = 0.1
                ),
                selectInput("colors", "Color Scheme",
                            rownames(subset(brewer.pal.info, category %in% c("seq", "div")))
                ),
                checkboxInput("legend", "Show legend", TRUE),
                p( iris %>%
                     e_charts() %>%
                     e_histogram(Sepal.Length, name = "histogram",breaks = "freedman-diaconis") %>%
                     e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") |> 
                     e_color(color = "#753732")
                   
                   )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  filteredData <- reactive({
    quakes[quakes$mag >= input$range[1] & quakes$mag <= input$range[2],]
  })
  
  # This reactive expression represents the palette function,
  # which changes as the user makes selections in UI.
  colorpal <- reactive({
    colorNumeric(input$colors, quakes$mag)
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # Use leaflet() here, and only include aspects of the map that
    # won't need to change dynamically (at least, not unless the
    # entire map is being torn down and recreated).
    leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(~min(long), ~min(lat), ~max(long), ~max(lat))
  })
  
  # Incremental changes to the map (in this case, replacing the
  # circles when a new color is chosen) should be performed in
  # an observer. Each independent set of things that can change
  # should be managed in its own observer.
  observe({
    pal <- colorpal()
    
    leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircles(radius = ~10^mag/10, weight = 1, color = "#777777",
                 fillColor = ~pal(mag), fillOpacity = 0.7, popup = ~paste(mag)
      ) %>% addTiles("http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                 attribution = paste(
                   "&copy; <a href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors",
                   "&copy; <a href=\"http://cartodb.com/attributions\">CartoDB</a>"
                 )
      ) 
  })
  
  # Use a separate observer to recreate the legend as needed.
  observe({
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map", data = quakes)
    
    # Remove any existing legend, and only if the legend is
    # enabled, create a new one.
    proxy %>% clearControls()
    if (input$legend) {
      pal <- colorpal()
      proxy %>% addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                          pal = pal, values = ~mag
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option -

Take the histogram plot on server side and use `echarts4rOutput` in the ui where you can easily adjust `height` and `width` according to your choice.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(htmltools)
library(echarts4r)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                sliderInput("range", "Magnitudes", min(quakes$mag), max(quakes$mag),
                            value = range(quakes$mag), step = 0.1
                ),
                selectInput("colors", "Color Scheme",
                            rownames(subset(brewer.pal.info, category %in% c("seq", "div")))
                ),
                checkboxInput("legend", "Show legend", TRUE),
                echarts4rOutput('hist_plot', height = '1000px', width = '500px')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  filteredData <- reactive({
    quakes[quakes$mag >= input$range[1] & quakes$mag <= input$range[2],]
  })
  
  # This reactive expression represents the palette function,
  # which changes as the user makes selections in UI.
  colorpal <- reactive({
    colorNumeric(input$colors, quakes$mag)
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # Use leaflet() here, and only include aspects of the map that
    # won't need to change dynamically (at least, not unless the
    # entire map is being torn down and recreated).
    leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(~min(long), ~min(lat), ~max(long), ~max(lat))
  })
  
  # Incremental changes to the map (in this case, replacing the
  # circles when a new color is chosen) should be performed in
  # an observer. Each independent set of things that can change
  # should be managed in its own observer.
  observe({
    pal <- colorpal()
    
    leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircles(radius = ~10^mag/10, weight = 1, color = "#777777",
                 fillColor = ~pal(mag), fillOpacity = 0.7, popup = ~paste(mag)
      ) %>% addTiles("http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                     attribution = paste(
                       "&copy; <a href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors",
                       "&copy; <a href=\"http://cartodb.com/attributions\">CartoDB</a>"
                     )
      ) 
  })
  
  # Use a separate observer to recreate the legend as needed.
  observe({
    proxy <- leafletProxy("map", data = quakes)
    
    # Remove any existing legend, and only if the legend is
    # enabled, create a new one.
    proxy %>% clearControls()
    if (input$legend) {
      pal <- colorpal()
      proxy %>% addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                          pal = pal, values = ~mag
      )
    }
  })
  
  
  output$hist_plot <- renderEcharts4r({
    iris %>%
         e_charts() %>%
         e_histogram(Sepal.Length, name = "histogram",breaks = "freedman-diaconis") %>%
         e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") %>%
         e_color(color = "#753732")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```